# How could I get items present inside Site Asset of a Team Site?

Tags: document-library, rest, site-collection, microsoft-graph, java-api

Through the following url :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives
```

I could get all user created document libraries and Documents (a system created document library), but I could not get other document libraries like Site Asset (present inside team site), Form Templates, Style library.

Please help me getting the items (Files, Folders, OneNote notebooks) present inside the Site Asset document library of a Team Site using Microsoft Graph API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default both the lists and drives enumerations attempt to hide system objects.

You can still see them, but you'll need to explicitly ask for them by requesting the system facet.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists?select=weburl,system
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives?select=weburl,system